# A severe error occurred on the current command. - Unknown Error

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

This is my code.

```
;With CTE as
(
select
    a.rn,
    a.LongDescription as ad,
    b.LongDescription as bd
from myTabl as a
    left join myTabl as b on a.rn +1 = b.rn
where
    a.rn=1
and
    a.LongDescription = 'Eric'
)
update CTE
    set ad += ' ' + b.LongDescription
from CTE as a
    left join myTabl as b on a.rn = b.rn+1
where
    a.rn=1
```

I was trying for answer of one question, while trying diff. options I came across following error,

```
Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.
```

What is this, I am not getting anything. Is there any major mistake in my code? I tried to google it but all results redirect me towards "Microsoft Fix". Can some please explain me in simple words that WHAT IS WRONG?

Comment: Have you tried following up with Sql Server Profiler?

Comment: it seems you've encountered an error condition in query engine (ie access violation...). You should have a minidump created in instance's log directory with more info in it. If you choose to open a case with Microsoft PSS, they will look into it to pinpoint the exact souce of error.

Comment: Is attempting to update a CTE even legal? You should try updating your actual table based on a query over your CTE instead. Also, I find it quite strange that you try to join your CTE result over `myTabl` again.

Comment: CTEs are updateable. Not in all circumsance, but you'd get a different error. Something about cannot modify underlying tables, I think.

Comment: That's valid; you can update in CTE as well but why you are joining back to the same table from which CTE created; rather do a self join while creating the CTE expression. Also, try running `DBCC` against your table `mytable`. Could be a corrupt index issue.

Comment: CTEs are updateable same as views. This is valid T-SQL. It's not perfect, but the optimizer should be able to deal with it. It doesn't. Any parsing or binding error will be caught and handled differently. It's highly unlikely that there is a corrupt index issue, because it's a made-up table OP was using in answering another question. It's a problem with the engine, and most likely solved in some newer build (which version we're talking about?). If you really need to get to the bottom of this, contact PSS. Thanks for the patience :)

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Did you locate the minidump file, were there any? Can you share the contents?

Comment: Please check this link, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/75abf/2

Comment: This works fine on 2008r2 SP1 (10.50.2550.0) and 2012 SP1 (11.0.3000.0). What's your build number? In any case, an error like this most likely created a minidump file, could you share it?

Comment: What is minidump fir? I am not aware about that.Version is  "Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2 10.50.1600.1"

Comment: @AK47 minidump is a text file generated by SQL Server on an error condition, like yours. It is located in the instance's log folder. For example, on my laptop it would be this folder: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log. Anything there? (pls use my name in answer so I'm notified)

Answer (score -1):

I guess you need to change the set line:

```
set ad = a.ad + ' ' + b.LongDescription
```

Check the SQL fiddle demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/743b7/1)

Comment: `+=` is a valid operator in INSERT statement. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms177523.aspx

Comment: Thanks @qxg. Personally, I don't like it as it sometimes hard to understand the logic there. If you split it to `set ad = ad + ' ' + b.LongDescription`, you will see another error, that's why I suggest spit them and use alias for that line.

Answer (score -1):

TRY THIS.................

```
;With CTE as
(
select
    a.rn,
    a.LongDescription as ad,
    b.LongDescription as bd
from myTabl as a
    left join myTabl as b on a.rn +1 = b.rn
where
    a.rn=1
and
    a.LongDescription = 'Eric'
)
update CTE
    set ad += ' ' + b.LongDescription
from CTE as a
    left join 
    ( select (rn+1) AS NewRN,* from myTabl )as b on a.rn = b.NewRN
where
    a.rn=1
```